# Why does non-executed compile-time code increase Raku's bytecode size? Does it slow runtime performance?

Tags: compilation, bytecode, raku, rakudo

Consider the following two programs:

```
unit module Comp;
say 'Hello, world!'
```

and

```
unit module Comp;
CHECK { if $*DISTRO.is-win { say 'compiling on Windows' }}
say 'Hello, world!'
```

Naively, I would have expected both programs to compile to exactly the same bytecode: the [`CHECK`](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers#CHECK) block specifies code to run at the end of compilation; checking a variable and then doing nothing has no effect on the run-time behavior of the program, and thus (I would have thought) shouldn't need to be included in the compiled bytecode.

However, compiling these two programs does *not* result in the same bytecode.  Specifically, compiling the version without the `CHECK` block creates 24K of bytecode versus 60K for the version with it.  Why is the bytecode different for these two versions?  Does this difference in bytecode have (or potentially have) a runtime cost?  (It seems like it must, but I want to be sure).

And one more related question: how do [`DOC CHECK`](https://docs.raku.org/language/phasers#DOC) blocks fit in with the above?  My understanding is that even the *compiler* skips `DOC CHECK` blocks when it's not run with the `--doc` flag.  Consistent with that, the bytecode for a hello-world program does *not* increase in size when given a `DOC CHECK` block like the one above.  However, it *does* increase in size if the block includes a `use` statement.  From that, I conclude that `use` is somehow special-cased and gets executed even in `DOC CHECK` blocks.  Is that correct?  If so, are there other simillarly special-cased forms I should know about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `CHECK` or `BEGIN` block (or other `BEGIN`-time constructs) may contain code that escapes. For example:

```
BEGIN SomeClass.^add_method('foo', anon method foo() { 42 })
```

Adds a method to a class, which exists beyond the bounds of the `BEGIN` block. That method's bytecode is therefore required in the compiled output. Currently, Rakudo conservatively includes the bytecode of everything in a `BEGIN` or `CHECK` block. It may be possible to avoid that for some simple cases in the future.

So far as the runtime cost goes, the implementation goes to some lengths to minimize the cost of bytecode that is never run (not so much for this case, but because the standard library is huge but many programs use only a fraction of it). For example:

- Bytecode is `mmap`'d, so some unused parts of it may not actually be paged into memory
- Bytecode is only validated on the first call to that frame
- Frame meta-data (what lexicals does it have) is only deserialized on the first call to the frame
- Unless something references it, the code object will not be deserialized

So far as `use` goes, its action is performed as soon as it is parsed. Being inside a `DOC CHECK` block does not suppress that - and in general can not, because the `use` might bring in things that need to be known in order to finish parsing the contents of that block.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the first part of your answer.  Given a file with `class SomeClass {}`, I understand that adding `BEGIN SomeClass.^add_method('foo', anon method foo() { 42 })` has a runtime effect – `SomeClass` now has a `foo` method, when it didn't before.  But that's the same runtime effect as declaring the class with `class SomeClass { method foo { 42 }`, and I would (again, naively) have expected them to compile to the same bytecode, just as a macro compiles to the same code as an expanded version of the macro.  But the two forms generate different bytecode.  What am I missing?

Comment: Also, thanks very much for the time you put into answering Raku questions on here.  Out of the last three questions I've asked, you've answered all three – and in each case have provided a very helpful answer that I couldn't have gotten from anyone without strong familiarity with Raku/Rakudo.  I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/3591) to add info from this question to the Raku docs and, once I understand this area a bit more fully, will ensure that info makes it into the docs.

Comment: @codesections When there's a `BEGIN`-time construct, it results in a nested bit of compile time, followed by the runtime of the `BEGIN` block, and only then parsing of the enclosing compile time resumes. The final compilation output somehow needs to bring those together; I suspect you're mostly seeing side-effects of that.